# emit events to all child nodes of a html dom element

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to emit an event to all deep childNodes of an element. What i am looking is event capturing using custom events or something equivalent.

one of the solution is to recursive loop through all children and then emit events to each one, but it is slower.

is there any better solution ?

Comment: I've faced the same issue... I didn't find an easy solution. Maybe it is time to use a framework. You might have to rethink your code.

Comment: yeah but the question is how frameworks does it ? is it some tricks that needed. or we are doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with *deep* childNodes, but `querySelectorAll` can select all elements at any nesting level starting from a root node:

```js
const elems = root.querySelectorAll("*")
const customEvent = new CustomEvent('custom')

elems.forEach(el => {
el.addEventListener("custom", (e) => console.log("Custom event received on element:", e.currentTarget))
el.dispatchEvent(customEvent)
})
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <button>B1</button>
  <p>P1</p>
  <div>
    <p>P2</p>
    <p>P3</p>
    <button>B2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that means i have to run a loop here, imagine runing a loop with 1000s of children + querySelector with "*" will take some good amount of time.

Comment: also querySelector with * doesn't return comment Nodes.